# How to keep GridBagLayout from changing the size of a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

In my FlashCardPanel class, I have a subpanel,LabelPanel, with a Grid Bag Layout. It consists of a constructor with an edit button, a button to "flip" the card, and the label to display the term/definition. My problem is that every time I click my "Flip" Button to display the definition of my term, the flip button will change size, usually matching the length of the definition.

Images of the problem
http://postimg.org/gallery/ymww3axq/

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class FlashCardPanel extends JPanel{


    private String term;
    private String definition;

    // shows the current text whether it is a term or definition
    private JLabel currentLabel;

    private static String NO_CARDS = "This set is empty";

    //current card being displayed
    private FlashCard currentCard;

    //new card that is added to the deck
    private FlashCard newCard;

    // true = term is showing; false = definition is showing
    private boolean termShowing = true;

    private AddNewCard frame;

    private CardSet cardSet;
    private int cardIndex = 0;

    private ButtonPanel bPanel;
    private LabelPanel lPanel;

    private static JButton flipButton;
    private static JButton nextButton;
    private static JButton prevButton;
    private static JButton addCard;
    private static JButton deleteCard;
    private static JButton editButton;



    public FlashCardPanel(CardSet cardSet) {
        this.cardSet = cardSet;
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        term = cardSet.get(0).getTerm();
        definition = cardSet.get(0).getDefintion();
        currentCard = cardSet.get(0);

        createButtons();

        lPanel = new LabelPanel();
        bPanel = new ButtonPanel();

        add(lPanel);
        add(bPanel);


    }

    public FlashCardPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        add(lPanel);
        add(bPanel);
    }

    private class LabelPanel extends JPanel {

            public LabelPanel() {
                this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                c.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);
                currentLabel = new JLabel(term);
                currentLabel.setText(cardSet.get(0).getTerm());


                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                add(editButton,c);



                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.ipady = 0;
                c.gridwidth = 0;
                c.weightx = 0;
                c.gridx = 2;
                c.gridy = 0;
                add(flipButton,c);

                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.ipady = 40;
                c.weightx = 0;
                c.gridwidth = 3;
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 3;
                add(currentLabel,c);

            }       
    }
    private class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

        public ButtonPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
            add(prevButton);
            add(nextButton);
            add(addCard);
            add(deleteCard);
        }
    }

    /*
     * creates buttons for the panel. Should be called before
     * any subpanel is created.
     */
    private void createButtons()
    {
         flipButton = new JButton(" Flip Card ");
         flipButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         flipButton.setActionCommand("1");

         nextButton = new JButton(" Next Card ");
         nextButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         nextButton.setActionCommand("2");

         prevButton = new JButton(" Previous Card ");
         prevButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         prevButton.setActionCommand("3");

         addCard = new JButton(" Add Card ");
         addCard.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         addCard.setActionCommand("4");

         deleteCard = new JButton(" Delete Card ");
         deleteCard.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         deleteCard.setActionCommand("5");

         editButton = new JButton("Edit");
         editButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         editButton.setActionCommand("6");   
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            int action = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());

            switch(action){

            case 1:
                flipCard();
                break;
            case 2:
                nextCard();
                break;
            case 3:
                previousCard();
                break;
            case 4:
                createFrame();
                break;
            case 5:
                deleteCard();
            case 6:
                createFrame(term,definition);
            }

        }

    }

    private void flipCard()
    {
        if (!cardSet.isEmpty()) {
        if (termShowing) {
            termShowing = false;
            currentLabel.setText(definition);
            }
        else {
            termShowing = true;
            currentLabel.setText(term);
            }
        }
        else {
            currentLabel.setText(NO_CARDS);
            term = "";
            definition = "";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This set is empty");
        }
    }

    private void nextCard() 
    {
        if (!cardSet.isEmpty()) {
        if (cardIndex == cardSet.size()-1) 
            cardIndex = 0;
        else 
            cardIndex++;

        term = cardSet.get(cardIndex).getTerm();
        definition = cardSet.get(cardIndex).getDefintion();

        if(termShowing)
            currentLabel.setText(term);
        else 
            currentLabel.setText(definition);

        currentCard = cardSet.get(cardIndex);
        }
        else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This set is empty");
    }

    private void previousCard()
    {
        if (!cardSet.isEmpty()) {
        if (cardIndex == 0) 
            cardIndex = cardSet.size()-1;
        else 
            cardIndex--;

        term = cardSet.get(cardIndex).getTerm();
        definition = cardSet.get(cardIndex).getDefintion();

        if(termShowing)
            currentLabel.setText(term);
        else
            currentLabel.setText(definition);

        currentCard = cardSet.get(cardIndex);
        }
        else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This set is empty");
    }
    /*
     * adding a card
     */
    private void createFrame() {
        frame = new AddNewCard(100,100,this);
    }
    /*
     * editing an existing card
     */
    private void createFrame(String t, String d)
    {
        frame = new AddNewCard(100,100,this,t,d);
    }


    public void addNewCard(String t, String d) {
        newCard = new FlashCard(t,d);
        cardSet.add(newCard);
        if (cardSet.isEmpty()) currentLabel.setText(newCard.getTerm());
    }

    public void editCard(String t, String d) {
        currentCard.setTerm(t);
        currentCard.setDefinition(d);
        if (termShowing) currentLabel.setText(t);
        else currentLabel.setText(d);

    }

    /*
     * Deletes current card on display
     */
    private void deleteCard()
    {   

        if (!cardSet.isEmpty()) {
        // if on the last card of the set
        if (cardIndex == cardSet.size()-1) cardIndex--;

        cardSet.remove(currentCard);

        if (!cardSet.isEmpty()) {
            currentCard = cardSet.get(cardIndex);
            currentLabel.setText(cardSet.get(cardIndex).getTerm());
        }
        else currentLabel.setText(NO_CARDS);
        }
        else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This set is empty");
    }


}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options including:

- using a nested JPanels each with its own layout. For instance the buttons could be placed into a GridLayout JPanel, and this placed into a BorderLayout JPanel with the label BorderLayout.CENTER
- I suggest that the long definition text be displayed within a JTextArea, not a JLabel. If you make it non-editable and remove borders, it could look like a JLabel.
- If you go this route, you will want to turn on word wrap on the JTextArea.
- You could swap JTextArea with JLabel (for the term) using a CardLayout.

Note, for future questions, please pare down  your problem. For instance, if this were my question, I'd create something like the code below, small, self contained, runnable and demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlashCardPanel2 extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private JLabel currentLabel;
   private String term = "Term";
   private String definition = "Definition: This will be a very long String to "
         + "illustrate the problem that you are having, and to try to help you get "
         + "a solution";
   private JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
   private JButton flipButton = new JButton(new FlipAction("Flip"));

   public FlashCardPanel2() {
      this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      c.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);
      currentLabel = new JLabel(term);  

      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.weightx = 0;
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      add(editButton, c);

      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 0;
      c.gridwidth = 0;
      c.weightx = 0;
      c.gridx = 2;
      c.gridy = 0;
      add(flipButton, c);

      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 40;
      c.weightx = 0;
      c.gridwidth = 3;
      c.gridx = 1;
      c.gridy = 3;
      add(currentLabel, c);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class FlipAction extends AbstractAction {
      public FlipAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String text = currentLabel.getText();
         text = (text.equals(term)) ? definition : term;
         currentLabel.setText(text);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FlashCardPanel2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new FlashCardPanel2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

And here's a potential solution with CardLayout and GridLayout and BorderLayout:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FlashCardPanel3 extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final String CURRENT_LABEL = "current label";
   private static final String DEFINITION = "definition";
   private JLabel currentLabel;
   private JTextArea currentDefinitionArea = new JTextArea(6, 20);
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
   private JPanel cardHolder = new JPanel(cardLayout);
   private String term = "Term";
   private String definition = "Definition: This will be a very long String to "
         + "illustrate the problem that you are having, and to try to help you get "
         + "a solution";
   private JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
   private JButton flipButton = new JButton(new FlipAction("Flip"));

   public FlashCardPanel3() {
      currentDefinitionArea.setOpaque(false);
      currentDefinitionArea.setText(definition);
      currentDefinitionArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      currentDefinitionArea.setLineWrap(true);
      currentDefinitionArea.setEditable(false);
      currentDefinitionArea.setFocusable(false);

      currentLabel = new JLabel(term, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      cardHolder.add(currentLabel, CURRENT_LABEL);
      cardHolder.add(new JScrollPane(currentDefinitionArea), DEFINITION);

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 0));

      buttonPanel.add(editButton);
      buttonPanel.add(flipButton);

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(cardHolder);
   }

   private class FlipAction extends AbstractAction {
      public FlipAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // String text = currentLabel.getText();
         // text = (text.equals(term)) ? definition : term;
         // currentLabel.setText(text);
         cardLayout.next(cardHolder);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FlashCardPanel2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new FlashCardPanel3());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I always try to shorten my questions when I ask. Every time I do, I'm always told that I'm not giving enough information that I think I didn't need to fix the issue. I find it hard trying to figure out what parts of my code are relevant/irrelevant.

Comment: @igknighton: Your code doesn't run (no main), doesn't compile (no FlashCard nor CardSet), has a whole bunch of code unrelated to the issue at hand,..... Now please look at my first program -- it compiles, it runs, if you run it it demonstrates the problem, and it has no dependencies on outside classes not provided such as FlashCard or CardSet. It is key that you work on isolating the problem as this skill is not only important here, but also in your own debugging efforts. It won't be wasted efforts.